# Publish APP to Android market, where to embed my own key?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I want to publish my application (which is not free) in android market with my own key. I got my encrypted key, but I don’t know where do I need to write this key? In which file I need to write this key? 
I read the dev Guide documentation of android and I also searched by myself but I don’t understand and I couldn’t find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the key if you have implemented licensing (http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html)